# clarification and support on 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, node-modules, loadmodule

I'm new with code and apps either launching or trial. Recently I've been trying to set up a node on my mac terminal and experienced the below problems....

ironfish start
/usr/local/Cellar/ironfish/75/libexec/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:121
throw e;
^

Error: The module '/usr/local/Cellar/ironfish/75/libexec/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 108. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1249:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at bindings (/usr/local/Cellar/ironfish/75/libexec/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
at Object. (/usr/local/Cellar/ironfish/75/libexec/node_modules/segfault-handler/index.js:3:37)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32) {
code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

I followed some solution similar to the err name but that didn't resolve it:

npm uninstall bcrypt
npm install bcryptjs
npm install bcrypt

it's not resolved. please assit

Comment: *The module ... was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 108. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93* - Either update your Node version, or downgrade the other module (if possible).